# Debug Request Timed Out (System.Web.HttpException)

Tags: asp.net, debugging, timeout, visual-studio-debugging

According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641.aspx) regarding system.web httpRuntime executionTimeout:

```
This time-out applies only if the debug attribute in the compilation element is
False.  Therefore, if the debug attribute is True, you do not have to set this
attribute to a large value in order to avoid application shutdown while you are
debugging.
```

That's a great feature for most debugging as it enables the request to stay alive during the debugging.  What if I want to debug a timeout error itself though?!  No matter what timeout properties I set anywhere .NET seems to allow unlimited time so I never catch the exception to debug with!

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to produce the long running execution locally, just go to the Debug menu, and choose "Break all". Then you can use the Debug -> Windows -> Threads view to look at all your active threads. You'll probably be able to determine what's taking so long.

Alternatively, you can set your Debug=false; then attach Visual Studio to your process, and set it to break on instances of ThreadAbortExceptions being thrown.

Alternatively, you can set DebugDiag to [capture a dump file](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asiatech/archive/2012/06/21/how-to-troubleshoot-httpexception-request-timed-out-asp-net-4-0-64-bit.aspx) when a long running execution is detected. You can use WinDbg (tough) or Visual Studio 2010 and above to load these dump files and inspect the running state of your program.

Finally, you could attempt to reflectively change the behaviour of the RequestTimeoutManager class, which periodically calls TimeoutIfNeeded(DateTime now). However, I can't trivially see a way to change this to use the behaviour of debug=false.